# How to populate a ViewModel object after joining two entities together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following viewModel class:-

```
public class RackJoin
    {
        public TMSRack Rack { get; set; }
        public Resource Resource { get; set; }
        public Technology Technology { get; set; }
        public ComponentDefinition ComponentDefinition { get; set; }
        public SDOrganization Site { get; set; }
        public SDOrganization Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

And the following Uncompleted Repository model method for join two entities:-

```
public IQueryable<TMSRack> AllFindRacks(string q)
        {
            List<RackJoin> rakjoin = new List<RackJoin>();
            var result = from rack in tms.TMSRacks
           .Include(rack => rack.DataCenter)
           .Include(rack => rack.Zone)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSFirewalls)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMsRouters)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSServers)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSStorageDevices)
           .Include(rack => rack.TMSSwitches)
           .Include(rack => rack.Technology)
                         join resource in entities.Resources
                         .Include(a => a.ComponentDefinition)
                           .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization)
                           .Include(a => a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization)
                         on rack.Technology.IT360ID equals resource.RESOURCEID
                         where (q == null || rack.Technology.Tag.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()))
                         select //not sure what i should write here;
```

**First Question**; But I am not sure how I can populate the `List<RackJoin>` based on the join outcomes, in the above method.

**Second Question** ; I am calling the above method from the following action method:-

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
            {
                var racks = repository.AllFindRacks(searchTerm).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, 5);
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView("_RackTable", racks);
                }
                return View(racks);
            }
```

So can I know how the paging and the join will work together , I mean will EF do the join for all the records that satisfy the where clause, then it will do the skip and take. and to which entities the skip and take will be applied?

Answer (score 1):

1st question:

You'll have access to both the range variables in the select, so you could have a view model with properties for both the rack and the resource.

```
select new RackJoin { 
         Rack = rack, 
         Resource = resource
     };
```

2nd question:

As long as you return IQueryable, EF should see the Skip and Take operators and apply them into the SQL query, so SQL Server is responsible for the joins and the paging.

Note: you can remove the new List line of code.

I have some more examples of using join in my [Standard LINQ Operators](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx) article. Hope that helps.